# How to authenticate firebase using email/password on desktop for individual users (javafx)

Tags: java, firebase, javafx, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still in the planning phase of a project. Is it possible to authenticate a user on desktop using java just to **read** data from firestore?

The only documentation I can find is related to admin access, which I don't think is a smart idea. I also saw something using webview from javafx if I understand correctly.

Can someone help me understand how to do this, or let me know if it's at least possible?

We have a mobile app that is creating and viewing data on firestore. My job is to find a way to make a desktop version that only reads the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate from any application by just making http requests to the firestore api: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

There are countless libraries for making http requests in java.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) help your use case, the solution is based on [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to read documents in the "cities" collection
    // only if they are authenticated.
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Add @Chris Hamilton provided client side approach to complete your solution.